# Visual Studio Code Python load own modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment, python-module

I am pretty new using python in Visual Studio Code. I am using Python3. I'm trying to import a own class from a file, but I can't find the right syntax in Visual Studio Code.

My structure:

```
└── CodeAna
    │ __init__.py
    ├── GetDB
    │   ├── GetData.py
    │   ├── __init__.py   
    │  
    ├── HelerTools
    │   ├── Helper.py
    │   ├── __init__.py   
    │  
    └── Analysis
        ├── GetAnalysis.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
```

In GetAnalysis.py, I need to import a class called GetDataDB, which is located in GetData.py. My solution would be:

```
import CodeAna.GetDB.GetData as dl
Data = dl.GetDataDB()
```

But then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Test/VSC_Codes/CodeAna/TestAnalysis/GetAnalysis.py", line 1, in <module>
    import GetDB.GetData.GetDataDB as dl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GetDB'
```

Doing that within **Spyder** it works. I am not suore what I am doing wrong here???

**Update:**

This is included in my setting.json file:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/anaconda3/bin/python"
}
```

still having the same problem also if pylint is showing no errors...

Comment: Your problem seems to be with your `PYTHONPATH` variable. In order to import `GetDataDB` using `import GetDB.GetData.GetDataDB as dl` you need to have the folder CodeAna in your PYTHONPATH

Comment: How should I do that? I am using macos

Comment: One more point I am using conda as path

Comment: How are you executing your code?

Answer (score 0):

`cd CodeAna && export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`

This should add your root dir to the Python Path then you can simply import as usual.

So,

In GetAnaylsis.py you would do: `import GetDB.GetData as dl`